# Set NSCollectionview Knob Proportion

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview, nsscroller

I have a `NSCollectionview` inside my macOS application and I want to control the knob proportion of the vertical `NSScroller`.

As I am loading more and more item into my collection view asynchronous, the proportion of the scroller is changing frequently and does not represent how many items there will be in the end. So if the user begins to scroll before all items are loaded, the knob shrinks while he's scrolling.

How can I set the knob proportion to an initial size, so I can represent how big the NSCollectionView will be in the end?

Comment: Are all items the same size and do you know the number of items from the start?

Comment: The items are not the same size but they are of similar size. I know the number of items from the start. But I think it's not important if the proportion is not 100% correct.

Comment: Show placeholders?

Comment: If I display over 5000 placeholders, it will not load smoothly.